# SQL SUM aggragete issue

Tags: sql

```
ID Title Qty

1  BMW   2

2  VW    3
```

I want in one SQL query to find a sum of quantity and divide it by current Qty.
For example:

`SUM (Qty) = 5`, so I want to compute scores by formula. 2/5 and 3/5

```
ID title newscores
1  BMW   2/5
1  vW    2/5
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9a7c51/9)

```
 SELECT id
,title
,qty/(select sum(qty) from cars) 
FROM cars 
GROUP BY id
```

Answer (score 0):

this should work

```
select title , sum (QTY) , t2.total, sum(QTY) / t2.total
from table , (select sum(QTY) as total from table) as t2
group by title
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select id, title, qty/(select sum(qty) from make)
from make
```

See [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6b17a/6).

Note there is no need whatsoever for a group by clause.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT ID, Title, CONCAT( Qty,  '/', (SELECT SUM( Qty) FROM table1) ) AS  'newscores'
FROM  `table1`
```